# Integrity constraint violation on Heroku. Can't load default values when deployed

Tags: php, laravel, heroku

My website works fine locally, but when I upload it to heroku and try to create user I get

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key 
constraint fails (`heroku_58d91081036dbb1`.`users`, CONSTRAINT `users_role_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY 
(`role_id`) REFERENCES `roles` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into `users` (`name`, `email`, 
`password`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Dominykas, d@s.com, 
$2y$10$yZb.rSEmsLQCkd.5HStt1.9DH6jiBQbyiixlessIVjSKCGErx9E1K, 2019-12-02 13:00:02, 2019-12-02 13:00:02))
```

As I found out, my default values in migration doesn't work

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('role_id')->default(2);
$table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles')->onDelete('cascade');
```

because when I seed new user and provide role_id, I don't get this error, but if I leave it for default value, It get an error

How should I fix it, maybe I should try another hosting provider?

Comment: has nothing to do with the host .. there is most likely not a role with id `2` in the database, you can't set that foreign key to a value that doesn't exist in the table it points to

Comment: Do you have a role with `id=2` in your `roles` table?

Comment: Thanks, just logged in via laragon to database, and saw, that instead of incrimenting normally by 1, it incremented by 10, my record now has id of 11 instead of 2. How should I fix that?

Comment: you probably shouldn't be setting a default in the migration, your code should be specifying it, and you can make that field nullable if needed

Comment: If you don't have any data you want to keep in your tables you could try with: `php artisan migrate:refresh --seed`. Note that this command will drop all of your tables (resetting the autoindex increment), will recreate all of the tables based on your migration files and seed your database. If everything is correct in your migrations/seeds it should work

Comment: Alright, for quick fix I set the value to 11 and migrated database. Will have to rewrite some code later, thanks

Comment: @mdexp It still autoindexes not how my app was build, It autoincrements by 10, heroku works differently

Comment: @lagbox It is incrementing by 10, first record has id 1, second has id 1+10 = 11, My site now works, you can look it up here http://dominykasrelative.herokuapp.com/

Comment: you are right, it is another one of those odd things heroku does because they have the weirdest setup in the world

Comment: @lagbox can you tell me where should I host my other laravel projects, I always worked in local enviroment,  it's time to level up

Comment: use who ever you would like, heroku is fine, it is just a non traditional setup, but it is very popular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so if your website works fine locally, but when deployed it gives errors related to database like `Integrity constraint violation` it's probably because you forgot that heroku increments tables by 10, for example id's would appear like this: `1, 11, 21, 31`

In my case I set default value to 2 which is foreign id of other table, well, in heroku it's now 11